# "error: use of deleted function" when calling std::move on unique_ptr in move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
    }

    A( const A&& rhs )
    {
        a = std::move( rhs.a );
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> a;
};
```

This code will not compile using g++ 4.8.4 and throws the following error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>
::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_de
lete<int>]’
     a = std::move( rhs.a );
       ^
```

I understand that the copy constructor and copy assignment constructor for unique_ptr are deleted and cannot be called, however I thought by using `std::move` here I would be calling the move assignment constructor instead. [The official documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) even shows this very type of assignment being done.

What is wrong in my code that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
A( const A&& rhs )
// ^^^^^
```

Drop the `const` -- moving from an object is destructive, so it's only fair that you can't move from a `const` object.

Comment: As a style point, prefer to use an initializer: `A(A&& rhs) : a(std::move(rhs.a)) {}`